# A theory for calculating mass and charge of electron

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electrons, mass, charge, string-theory

I wonder if we have such a fundamental theory in which we could calculate mass and charge of electron?

And if string theory could do this then why it is said we have no practical experiment for string theory at current time?

Comment: Did you read that string theory can currently calculate these two values?

Comment: No I didn't. I don't read string theory. yet! @G.Smith

Answer (score -1):

String theorists have been unable to calculate the mass of the electron,though that was one of the initial goals when it was introduced in the 1970's.
The last time I looked the 'phenomenology' arising from string theory had failed to account for any of the particles observed in nature in a convincing way.